# R Markdown - HTML Output in Powerpoint

Tags: r-markdown, r-highcharter

I try to get Highouts Output in my Powerpoint presentation, but the suggestion does not work .This feature is still pretty new and I was not able to find something valueable in the docu.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  beamer_presentation: default
  powerpoint_presentation: default
  ioslides_presentation: default
  always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(highcharter)
```

### R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting 
syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more 
details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that 
includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code 
chunks within the document.

### Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

### Slide with R Output

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
    highchart() %>%
      hc_add_series(data = mtcars, type = "bar", hcaes(y = cyl))
```

### Slide with Plot

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Produces:

```
Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting pptx output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: yes

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.
```

I added the always_allow_html: yes part to the top, but it still does not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: remove the indents before `always_allow_html: yes`. It is not a part of the output section.

Comment: facepalm on me... Did not see that, thank you